# How to fix SVG being cut off when using as background?

Tags: html, css, svg, background-image, scale

I'm currently experiencing an issue with my SVG, where it seems to be cut off when it is resized on a larger screen. I've attempted various adjustments to the preserveAspectRatio attribute without success.

I've explored multiple methods, but none seem to produce the desired result. I aim to have the SVG scalable based on the screen size while ensuring that the image covers the entirety of the SVG without resizing.

Any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

[This is the look i'm going for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDeZj.png)

**Updated**
I'm encountering an issue with fitting the SVG to the full height of its container. Presently, it appears too large and gets cut off. I attempted to use preserveAspectRatio(xMidYMid meet), but it doesn't stretch to fill the container. Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

```css
        img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .child1 {
            background-color: #242321;
        }

        .parent {
            height: 500px;
            display: flex;
        }

        .grey-rectangle {
    position: relative;
}

.grey-rectangle::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("https://dummyimage.com/1080x1920/000/fff.png") center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-mask: url("https://cdn.glitch.global/8b3c1190-f7e6-419e-b631-a2620293ee60/rectangle.svg?v=1709712041215#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(xMidYMid meet))") top center no-repeat;
    mask: url("https://cdn.glitch.global/8b3c1190-f7e6-419e-b631-a2620293ee60/rectangle.svg?v=1709712041215#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(none))") top center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div style="padding: 30px;"></div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child1" style="width: 70%;">
            <img src="https://cdn.glitch.global/8b3c1190-f7e6-419e-b631-a2620293ee60/left-child.png?v=1709739934821">
            <div class="child1-container">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grey-rectangle" style="width: 30%; height: 100%;">
            
        </div>
    </div>
```

Past Method (the svg is being cut off)

```
    <style>
.icon {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('https://cdn.glitch.global/8b3c1190-f7e6-419e-b631-a2620293ee60/rectangle.svg?v=1709712041215') no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}
.icon-kitten { 
    -webkit-mask: url('rectangle.svg#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(none))') no-repeat 0% 50%;
  background: url(https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.png) 50% 0%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.parent {
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden; 
}
    </style>
<div class="parent" style="height: 500px; display: flex;">
    <div class="child1" style="width: 50%; height: 100%; background-color: bisque;"></div>
    <div class="icon icon-kitten" style="width: 50%; height: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks as tho' you want the height to be full height of the container and width to be the width - is that right? If so I can't see why contain or cover will help you as both maintain the aspect-ratio of the original.

Comment: @AHaworth
I'm looking to have the image contained within the SVG, which is why I'm exploring the contain and cover options. However, despite removing these options, I'm still encountering difficulties getting the desired outcome.

Do you have any other suggestions or recommendations on how I can achieve this?